# .htaccess: dynamic rules and forbid all

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, web

I have the following architecture in my project :

Application/
 Modules/
  Example/
   Controllers/
   Views/
   Web/
    css/
     style.css
    img/
Core/
index.php

I'd like to redirect all of the REQUET_URI to my index.php. This is easy with the following .htaccess content:

```
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}             !index\.php
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$                          index.php/$1 [L]
```

But now if I request www.domain.ext/Application/Modules/Example/Web/css/style.css, it won't work. It's what I expect because I want to rewrite the url for my "modules" like: www.domain.ext/ModuleName/[...]
The previous link would give me the file  www.domain.ext/Application/Modules/ModuleName/Web/[...]

For example: www.domain.ext/ModuleName/css/style.css would give me the file www.domain.ext/Application/Modules/ModuleName/Web/css/style.css
The same for www.domain.ext/ModuleName/my_file.xml => www.domain.ext/Application/Modules/ModuleName/Web/my_file.xml
and so on..

But I have no idea how to do that. I want keep all of the directories "Deny from all".

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^Application/Modules/ Application/Modules/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]

# not already rewritten
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
# not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# forward to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: At the beginning I was using the same pattern, but I can't do the "shortcut" for the file. the URI /ModuleName/css/style.css should give me the file /Application/Modules/ModuleName/Web/css/style.css

Comment: That css thing appear to be a different requirement that you haven't mentioned in your question. Can you clarify all the requirements clearly by editing your question.

Comment: I have edited the original post :) It was just an example of what I'd to have. Hope it will help you !

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming that you wish to be able to access the slug inside your `index.php` file, you can do this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?request=$1 [L]
```

Comment: It's what I have currently.
Actually I'd like to process like:
1. Check if the REQUEST_URI match to the syntax for a file (like a shortcut)
2. If it's not a shortcut for a file, redirect to index.php/[URI]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Rewrite if the file does not exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index\.php

# Rewrite any assets file
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*).(css|js|png|jpe?g|xml|gif)$ index.php/Application/Modules/$1/$2.$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*).(css|js|png|jpe?g|xml|gif)$ index.php/Application/Modules/$1/$2/$3.$4 [L]
```

These rules should redirect:

`www.domain.ext/Example/css/style.css`

to

`www.domain.ext/Application/Modules/Example/Web/css/style.css`

And

`www.domain.ext/ModuleName/my_file.xml`

to

`www.domain.ext/Application/Modules/ModuleName/Web/my_file.xml`

**EDIT:** Sorry, it was my mistake, I was doing wrong the rules

According to my tests, this gives me 500 error internal:

```
index.php/Application/Modules/$1/$2.$3 [L]
```

But if I use QUERY_STRING `?` it works

```
index.php?Application/Modules/$1/$2.$3 [L]
---------^
```

So its better to use a QUERY_STRING variable like:

```
index.php?page=Application/Modules/$1/$2.$3 [L]
```

And retrieve the content in php with:

```
<?php

$page = $_GET['page']; // Application/Modules/Example/Web/css/style.css
```

Comment: It's waht I'm looking for but reversing ! www.domain.ext/Example/css/style.css should redirect to ww.domain.ext/Application/Modules/Example/Web/css/style.css ! I'll try to reverse it by myself ;)

Comment: Oh man, sorry about that, I was doing the rules in wrong way, now see my edit